# fetch public facebook events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to fetch all events from a public page. I'm sure that appID and appSecret is correct and i still getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature. thrown in /var/www/Events/facebook/src/base_facebook.php on line 1325
```

i've also added the site url to the facebook developer app. i've followed several threads answer, but keep getting same error again and again. What am i doing wrong in order to fetch the event data?

```
ob_start();

require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';

$fb = new Facebook(array(
       'appid'=>'APPID',
       'secret'=>'APPSECRET'
      ) );

$page_events = $fb->api('/ikeausa/events', 'GET');
printf ('<pre>%s</pre>', $page_events);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked the same question again! But I noticed a big error this time:

Instead of `'appid'` it should be `'appId'`. (note the capital **I**).

But another thing: no event of **ikeausa** is public, so you'll get an empty array in result. Try following, it will give you an event that is public-

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'=>'app-id',
   'secret'=>'app-secret'
  ));
$page_events = $fb->api('/Shadowfax.sahil/events', 'GET');
print_r($page_events);
```